# Python: Family-class

Tags: python

I'm implementing a "person"-class with the arguments name, title, and children.
The function "desc" should return a list of the persons which are below the family tree.

So far, I've done this:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, title, children=None):
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        if children is None:
            self.children = []
        else:
            self.children = children


    def desc(self):
        self.out = []
        if self.children:
            for kid in self.children:
                self.out.append(kid)
            return self.out


p1 = Person("p1", "test")
p2 = Person("p2", "test", children = [p1])
p3 = Person("p3", "test")
p4 = Person("p4", "test", children = [p2, p3])
p5 = Person("p5", "boss", children = [p4])
print [person.title for person in p5.desc()]
# desired output:
# ['test', 'test', 'test','test']
print [person.name for person in p5.desc()]
# desired output:
# ['p4', 'p2', 'p1', 'p3']
```

But my actual output does not look like the desired one. 
So, my question is: how would you save the children? In a simple list? The problem is clearly in def desc().
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this work? Shouldn't `george` and all names be strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to recurse over the `children` lists:

```
def desc(self):
    out = []
    for kid in self.children:
        out.append(kid)
        out.extend(kid.desc())
    return out
```

This uses the `desc()` method on the current object, then calls that same method on each listed child to extend the current result list. This continues on until objects with no children are encountered.

Note that `out` doesn't need to be an attribute on the instance; I've kept a local variable instead.

This produces your expected output:

```
>>> class Person():
...     def __init__(self, name, title, children=None):
...         self.name = name
...         self.title = title
...         if children is None:
...             self.children = []
...         else:
...             self.children = children
...     def desc(self):
...         out = []
...         for kid in self.children:
...             out.append(kid)
...             out.extend(kid.desc())
...         return out
... 
>>> p1 = Person("p1", "test")
>>> p2 = Person("p2", "test", children = [p1])
>>> p3 = Person("p3", "test")
>>> p4 = Person("p4", "test", children = [p2, p3])
>>> p5 = Person("p5", "boss", children = [p4])
>>> print [person.title for person in p5.desc()]
['test', 'test', 'test', 'test']
>>> print [person.name for person in p5.desc()]
['p4', 'p2', 'p1', 'p3']
```

So `p5.desc()` adds `p4` to the `out` list, then extends the list with the result of `p4.desc()`. `p4.desc()` adds `p2` to it's local `out` list, extends it with the result of `p2.desc()`, then adds `p3` to `out` and extends it with `p3.desc()`, etc.